# Equal, is equal to, equals, are equal to

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Which is correct?

Given 240 kph (240 kilometres per hour) = 149 mph (149 miles per hour)

How does one say this?

> -240 kph **equal** 149 mph.
>   -240 kph **equals** 149 mph.
>   -240 kph **is equal to** 149 mph.
>   -240 kph **are equal to** 149 mph.

Is 240 kph *singular* or *plural* (kilometre or kilometres)?
Or 240 kph is a separate kind of thing?

Comment: `kilometers per hour` is plural, of course `miles per hour` is also plural.

Comment: *Equals* is correct, as is *is equal to*. There are some instances when one might use *are*, but that would be limited to when a quantity separates *are* from *equal to*, and would *sound* correct, but not necessarily be mathematically correct.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Correct ones are:

240kph equals 149mph; 
240kph is equal to 149mph;

In 240kph, kilometres is plural.

Comment: "240 kph" is singular; the third person singular of the verb is "equals", and the third person plural would be "equal"

Comment: @PhilSweet Who says?

Comment: @DJClayworth Nothing in my answer is at variance with what you have said.  Written as *kph*, it is clearly singular. Indeed even the term *kilometres per hour* is singular. Nonetheless *kilometres* in this formulation is written in the plural.

Answer (score 10):

Even though the unit is "kilometers per hour," it's not really a "discrete" entity. You can't separate kilometers per hour from one another, and thus the unit acts as a "corporate" noun, where all the component "parts" belong to a larger unified whole. I would therefore opt for the singular:

> 240 kilometers per hour is equal to (*or* equals) 149 miles per hour.

Comment: You may also see **is equvalent to** to emphasize that it's a unit conversion rather than an equation.